# GenieBuilder, no-code editer can not open

Tags: julia, genie.jl

I want to use Julia's GenieBuilder to create a web application. The GenieBuilder service has been successfully started in vscode, but after the app is created, the codeless mode cannot be opened. Julia's version is 1.8.5

After I click the app.jl.html file, I cannot open the codeless editor, and can only open a blank file

Comment: Have you tried the example here? https://genieframework.com/blog/how-to-quickly-turn-your-julia-code-into-a-web-app-with-genie-builder/

Comment: (┬┬﹏┬┬) It is very sad that I failed to open the no-code interface in the first step. Do I have to build the data processing script first, or can I design the user interface of the APP through the no-code editor first, and then write the processing logic?